# Почему при четкой команде ==, дейстие не выполняется, скажите что не так?

Tags: c++, алгоритм

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

static std::string revRot(const std::string &strng, unsigned int sz)
{
    int counter=((strng.length())/sz); 
    int m_int;
    string source{strng};
    string temp{};
    string result{};
    int intResult{};
        int m_sz=(int)sz;
        if(m_sz==0)
        {
        cout<<"ops";
        return "hello";
        }

    for(int i{};i<counter;++i)
    {
      intResult=0;
      temp=source.substr(0,sz);
      source.erase(0,sz);
      for(int x{};x<temp.length();++x)
      {
        int zzz=(int)temp[x];
        zzz=zzz*zzz*zzz;
        intResult+=zzz;
      }
    if(intResult%2!=0)
    {
      char m_tempS=temp[0];
      for(int i{};i<temp.length()-1;++i)
      temp[i]=temp[i+1];
      temp[temp.length()-1]=m_tempS;
    }
    else
    {
      for(int i{};i<temp.length()/2;++i)
      {
       char m_tempS=temp[i]; 
       temp[i]=temp[(temp.length()-1)-i];
       temp[(temp.length()-1)-i]=m_tempS;
      }
    }  
    result+=temp; 
    } 
    return result;
    }
int main()
{
string xx{"563000655734469485"};
string temp=revRot(xx,0);
cout<<temp;
}
```

// у меня в задаче иногда второй параметр может быть равен нулю, так что нужно вернуть "" 
//чтобы заработала функция положите любое другое число во второй параметр. Функция работает правильно, но нужно чтобы при нуле второго параметра или при значении второго параметра больше чем длина строки первого параметра, должна выходить с ""; Но даже ставя просто `cout` при

```
if (sz==0) {
   cout << "действие"; 
   return " ";
}
```

просто закрывается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А вот эта строчка

```
int counter=((strng.length())/sz);
```

что делает при `sz` равном нулю?

Comment: Вы вообще человек?) Немогли бы сказать чем вы занимаетесь в жизни? Мне кажется вы работаете в Наса. (нет, серьездно где вы работаете? простите за излишний интерес)

Comment: В профиле написано, где я работаю.

Comment: Вы очень крутой, незнаю что вас мотивирует помогать людям)